# Will react fire a state change if the prev and next state are the same?

Tags: performance, reactjs

On my state change handler should I need to do the following:

```
deviceSize = ...
this.setState((prevState) => {
  if (prevState.deviceSize != deviceSize) {
    return {
      deviceSize
    }
  } else {
    return null
  }
})
```

Or is the following enough

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      deviceSize
    }
})
```

My concern is if I return something it will do some UI update.

Comment: if the state is the same, then there will be nothing to update. TL;DR your 2nd example is enough if your components are pure

Comment: why would you call set state if there is no state change? you shouldn't be doing that in the first place

Comment: Calling setState will **always** trigger a shouldComponentUpdate and full run of the render function, if shouldComponentUpdate returns true (or there is no shouldComponentUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong here. setState never check for values. When it is called, it just re-render view.

To check component should re-render or not,check `shouldComponentUpdate() method.`

```
`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` {

   1. it is triggered before the re-rendering process .
   2. It tells render() method should be called or not.
   3. If nothing changed, you can avoid re-render by returning false.
}
```

Comment: The problem with shouldComponentUpdate is everything underneath will no longer update according to this... https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2904-shouldcomponentupdate-will-short-circuit-an-entire-subtree-of-components-in-reactjs.htm

Comment: Yeah. If nothing changed, than why are you worried ? if State is same than technically nothing changed .

Comment: Because the rendered components may use `this.state` value in which case that won't matter

Comment: But what if it had their own state which gets changed only within the component.

Comment: Anyway I am just thinking of letting it set the state regardless and hope virtual DOM is fast enough for now.  I can optimize it later.

Comment: If state is not changed than, child components are already using it previous value which is same as current.

Comment: And, other thing what you can do is, Put shouldComponentUpdate inside child component rather than parent. Pass state to child as props and among  child components you choose which one to update and which not.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` fires a lot, and unless you know what you are doing you can make your app less performant with shouldComponentUpdate as opposed to an additional render cycle. I would caution you to only use it if the logic for your return value is fairly simple and it doesn't do a whole lot.

Comment: @JohnRuddell You are correct. This is the reason, React not compares the value before re-render.

Comment: Which is why you probably shouldn't do it. If they dont its for a reason. its a potential risk that can be avoided

Comment: @JohnRuddell we need to do it sometime.

Comment: I agree that it can be used sometimes if absolutely necessary, but i dont think its needed in this case. It can be avoided for this particular use case

Comment: @JohnRuddell totally agree. Before using anything, we must know the  use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go this route at all. You should not be calling setState unless you know its time to setState.

[You should read the docs on setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Use `componentDidUpdate` to know when to call setState. Like the docs say

> Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic
>   instead.

For instance

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.something !== something) { // you can compare previous state or props with current state or props
        this.setState({something: something});
    }
}
```

notice that setState is only called when you actually want to call it